# In R - Passing functions and their parameters as parameters to top order function

Tags: r, functional-programming, dynamic-programming

I am trying to do something much more complex than my example below, but the basic idea is encapsulated in this example:

```
pass_thru <- function(FUN,params){
  n <- length(FUN)
  out <- list()
  for(i in 1:n){
    temp <- get(FUN[i],mode="function")
    out[[i]] <- temp(params[[i]])
  }
  return(out)
}


fun1 <- function(x,y,z){
  x+y+z
}

fun2 <- function(l,m,n){
  l*m*n
}

FUN = c("fun1","fun2")
params = list(c(x=1,y=2,z=3,
                l=4,m=5,n=6))

pass_thru(FUN,params)
```

The passing and parsing of FUN within pass_thru() works fine, but passing params as a list only works if every element of params is a single value (only one parameter passed to each function of FUN).  I am not sure how to get multiple parameters to each function in FUN to be passed to the appropriate FUN.

What I really want to be able to do is to pass some of the parameters to each FUN in my call to pass_thru(), and have the body of pass_thru calculate the rest of the parameters to be passed to fun1 and fun2.

I am trying to create a flexible architecture upfront for large-scale data analysis, so having the ability to pass functions as well as any or all of those functions' parameters to other functions would be of great help.  Thank you for any insights you have into this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `do.call` like this and also fix `params` as shown:

```
params <- list(list(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3), list(l = 4, m = 5, n = 6))  
pass_thru <- function(FUN, params) Map(do.call, FUN, params)

pass_thru(FUN, params)
```

giving:

```
$fun1
[1] 6

$fun2
[1] 120
```

If you really did want:

```
params2 <- list(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3, l = 4, m = 5, n = 6)
```

then try this noting that the `params[intersect(...)]` part picks out the relevant parameters for the function call:

```
pass_thru2 <- function(FUN, params) {
   runf <- function(f) do.call(f, params[intersect(names(params), names(formals(f)))])
   lapply(FUN, runf)
}

pass_thru2(FUN, params2)
```

giving the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I figured out the do.call() approach not long after posting this, and was going to post an answer to my own question, but I REALLY like your params[intersect(...)] approach.   I may not use that for this implementation, but now that I know that trick, I can see several other really useful applications for this, so THANKS!